# Making a label inside a user control click through-able for all mouse events?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls, event-handling

I have a custom button control. There is obviously a label inside it for the text, and when I click on the label it obviously doesn't trigger the buttons click, event, or mouseenter, or mouseleave. What I need to do is make the label act like its not even there (click-throughable) . What I used to do is:

```
base.Click += value;
foreach (Control i in Controls) {
    i.Click += value;
}
```

this used to work fine, but now I have my button's label be a different colco each time the mouse hovers over it, so i go over the button, it becomes one color (lets say red), then i go over the label and it becomes green, then back over to the label-free part, and its yellow. This looks pretty bad so I need it to ignore the label all together.

Comment: The best you can do is subscribe to all mouse events and delegate them up to base (button), and make background transparent.

Comment: thats what i've been doing, its the labels ForeGround color thats the problem, since its being generated randomly, its hard to make it not change when its over the label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a label.  Too much of a pain and far too expensive.  Override the button's OnPaint() method to draw the text.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way which can make the behaviour uniform, but it might look equally unconventional.

First set `FlatStyle` property of the button to `Flat`. So that takes away the default visual effects which happens on mouse hovering.

Second, set `FlatAppearance.MouseDown and MouseHover` properties (you can do it in designer) the color u prefer.

Third, since label's doesnt have `FlatAppearance` property, you have to set it manually by hooking the `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave` events of the label and set the colour u want. (Hope you will initially give the label the `BackColor` the same as button's when you dont have mouse over both button and label).

Fourth, You should also hook the Button `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave` events to set the label the required color too..

Pretty hackish.. I assume clicking part is ok for u now.

Answer (score 0):

A new answer is to apply css style "pointer-events-none" to the label this allows the user to click through the label and activate
element behind.